# Can I give Template name to Ember components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to something like this:

```
App.SimplyHelloComponent = Em.Component.extend({
                       classNames: ['bold', 'italic', 'blue']

                       templateName:'my-temp'
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer edited in response to your comments

After your comments I did some testing and you where right, to have everything working correctly you should follow the conventions and name your class name the same as your template, so the template for `EmberTestComponent` should be called `components/ember-test`.

For example assume you have this component class:

```
App.EmberTestComponent=Ember.Component.extend({
  templateName:'components/ember-test'
});
```

Then your template should be like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/ember-test">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{body}}</p>
</script>
```

But since this is the default behaviour, defining the `templateName` in your component class can also be omitted resulting in a simple class definition like:

```
App.EmberTestComponent=Ember.Component.extend({});
```

However it is important that your template includes the `components` prefix. And it's also important that by convention the component template name **must** include a `"-"` in it's name.

You then use your custom component like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#each}}
    {{ember-test title=title body=body}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Note also how we pass the needed parameters to the component, `title` and `body`, this is necessary since your component does not know anything about it's context, it will only refer to the information we pass into it, that's the whole point of a component BTW.
As you can see it contains inside the variable names we set when we uses the component in the template.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i think components are entirely driven by template....if i write a hanler `App.EmberTestComponent=Ember.Component.extend({

  templateName:'components/hello-world',
  handleclick:function(){
   alert("Handler called") ;
  }


});
 ` then it did'nt work but if u will define a component in your app same name as template then handler get invoked find a [LINK TO BIN](http://jsbin.com/AdOVala/59/edit)

Comment: and if you make a conventional component same name as handlebar template then handler gets called [link to bin](http://jsbin.com/AdOVala/62/edit)

Comment: @vinay3206, you where right, I've edited my answer to reflect the correct way.

Comment: @intutivepixel so is final i cant give a cutom name to my conponent template

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify a template name.  I just tried and it works.  Here's how:

```
App.SimplyHelloComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    layoutName: 'components/my-temp'

});

script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-temp">
...
</script>
```

Now you would call your component like this:

```
{{simply-hello}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but `'components/'` is added as a prefix to the `templateName` provided for the lookup.

So if you want to use the name `'my-temp'`, use

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-temp">
...
</script>
```

for an inline template or have your build tools precompile your `my-temp` template from the `components/` template subdirectory.

Comment: if i define my template like this then with what name i have to use my component is handlebars {{simply-hello}} or{{my-temp}}

Comment: I have this: [link](http://jsbin.com/AdOVala/52/edit?html,css,js,console) at jsbin but its not working